# Complex multisite product entry with different tax rules

Tags: magento2, shipping, tax

We are setting up different stores with own product entry, metric system, currency, etc.
Like US, EU, UK. All products should be displayed on every store view, displays depending from location.

Challenge here is that a product entered within US store should reflect local tax if delivery address is within US. But on other sites it reflects excluding VAT.

However, how to deal if there is a combined order with products from both EU as US, in terms of;

- tax calculation
- shipping calculation

Is there any recommendation how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can manage for tax :
Stores -> Taxes -> Tax Rules

Here you can create tax rules for particular country by adding(Add New Tax Rate) with * as all state.

And same way
Stores -> Taxes -> Tax Zone and Rates here you will get provision to select country and its states directly.

For Shipping,
You can create price rule, here you can add conditions for shipping rates according to country.

Hope this could be helpful.